# Confusion about  git; how to undo?

Tags: uninstall, git, install-from-source, version-control

I wanted to install some source code that was on git.  Don't really know what that means ; I've never used git before, but I figured it was time to learn so,

- I first installed git.
- Next I tried to clone the git directory of the software I want to install.
- I got a message saying "the authenticity of (IP) can't be established".  I went ahead and ended up with another message saying, "warning, such and such will be added to known hosts."  I went ahead, and it said something about hanging up on the connection.

After searching the internet for a while I realized I didn't need git to install the software but now I have it installed, and have added some host to some file or another.  I'm concerned I've created some security issues I need to fix.

Can anyone help me undo what I've done, or better understand what I've done.  Did adding a git project open up my system?  Beyond that can anyone tell me how git works.  Everything I've found assumes I know stuff that I don't yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[Git](http://git-scm.com/documentation) is a version control system (a [DVCS](http://www.infoq.com/articles/dvcs-guide) to be more exact).  A VCS (version control system) on a server (or on a computer, or in the cloud), is used to store and track changes to data.  This just means that there is a repository of files (usually code in some programming language, along with configuration, instructions, etc.), and in addition to sitting on a server, it has changes made to it tracked across time.  The version control system keeps track of any changes to any file in a project, and these projects are hosted, and frequently public or shareable.

A version control system with a front-end (whether git, or subversion/svn, [bazaar/bzr](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/why-switch-to-bazaar.html), [mercurial/hg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/), etc.) really just allows you to install applications (or packages, code, scripts, patches) that aren't available or up-to-date in the standard channels. Another way to put this is that it allows the authors of the code to share it with you and others.

Git (or another VCS) does this by pulling in all of the data from a repository (the remote IP.IP.IP.IP in your example) and dropping into a directory (that you choose, ultimately) on your system.   By itself, this does nothing, unless you are actually running the code that you've gotten.

When you are using a VCS, having gotten the code doesn't necessarily mean you are going to run it as a complete suite.  You might test it, update it, merge in some changes, take out some pieces.   But in some cases, you can install complete applications (or more) from a repository.
If you can be sure that the code is safe, then this is a great way to play around with goodies that might not be available otherwise.

Having `git` on your system is unlikely to be a problem.  If you're tight on space, you can remove it from the software center or with 
`sudo apt-get remove git`.  (There might be additional packages, depending on how you installed it.)

It's hard to know how to undo anything that might have been done with downloaded code without knowing what it is that you've downloaded.  You might start by doing something like `ls -lart` in your home directory (from the command line), or looking in Nautilus file manager for recently modified directories.   For both of these methods, you're looking for the last changed directories files, some of which might be the ones you pulled onto your system with git.  If you find that, you'll have a better idea if there's anything else you need to remove or get help with undoing.

As far as the adding the host, I'm pretty sure that @Christoph (as well as @psusi) is correct.  The easiest way to rollback ssh key changes you have made is to do this:

```
 buntubox#$  rm -i ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Note that this will delete the entire known_hosts file.  This isn't usually a problem, because it will be rebuilt as you ssh to additional or repeat hosts. 
Alternately, you can edit the file (with gedit, nano, etc.) and remove lines you don't need. (Each line is associated with a remote host.) Again, this should be safe to do -- at worst, you'll have to accept new keys when logging into systems you've logged into before.

Comment: to add something here: the thing where it added some host to some file is probably that the ssh security key of the server you connected to was added to the ssh known hosts file at ~/.ssh/known_hosts. see http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/unix/sshknownhosts.html for more info

Answer (score 4):

The message you got was from ssh, which was probably the protocol you were using to connect to the git server.  Ssh remembers the fingerprint of remote servers you have used in the past so that when you try to connect again, it can verify that it is actually the same server, and not someone trying to impersonate that server.  Naturally the first time you connect, it can't do this, which is what it was warning you about.  What you saved was the fingerprint so that future connections can be verified as being to the legitimate server.